# standard-deviation function returns error in Lisp-Stat

Tags: common-lisp, xlispstat

I'm a complete newbie to Lisp-Stat, and I started working through the tutorial at https://lisp-stat.dev/docs/tutorials/basics, but when I type

`(standard-deviation purchases)`

(with purchases defined as a list of integers as in the tutorial), I get the error:

`#<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION DISTRIBUTIONS:STANDARD-DEVIATION (1)> when called with the arguments ...`

after which it repeats the list referenced by purchases. It gives me the same thing if I use some floating-point numbers as well.

I'm using SBCL in SLIME on Ubuntu 22.04.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a documentation bug, now fixed. Use `standard-deviation` to obtain the standard deviation of a *distribution*, and `sd` to obtain the standard deviation of a *sample*.  We should probably consolidate these two into a single generic function.

Also, although you can get an answer from any channel, for doc bugs and tutorial specific things it's probably easier to raise a github issue.  You can do that from within the documentation using the links at the top right of the page.  That way they'll be tracked.